# How to save additional entity while persisting another in Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've got a `Place` entity and a `Distance` one, like so:

```
class Place
{
    /** @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer") @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") */
    private $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=62, nullable=false) */
    private $name;

    /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Distance", mappedBy="origin") */
    protected $distancesTo;

    /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Distance", mappedBy="destination") */
    protected $distancesFrom;
}

class Distance
{
    /** @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer") @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") */
    private $id;

    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Place", inversedBy="distancesTo") */
    protected $origin;

    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Place", inversedBy="distancesFrom") */
    protected $destination;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
    private $miles;
}
```

I want that every time a new `Distance` (from Place_A to Place_B) is saved, the reverse distance (from Place_B to Place_A) gets inserted too in the DB. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create listener and listen for persisting on `Distance` entity. While it persists you can create new `Distance` with reverse route.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelSivolobov. Could you elaborate on "listen for persisting"? Which event should I listen to, `prePersist`, `postPersist`, another one? Also, as for the event listener, would it be better to use a LifeCycle callback or a proper separated event listener?

Comment: I think that it does not matter because you will work with another entity. But I would recommend you to use `prePersist` because you will have your queries executed in one transaction. LifeCycle callbacks are not for that purpose. they can be used when you need do some modifications in your entity while persisting.

Comment: I created an event listener for the `prePersist` event but I am [stuck with an infinite loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30576245/2516943).